# Angular ui-router pass parameter within the URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I know I can pass parameters when changing pages like this:

```
$state.go('index.my_route', {my_param : value});
```

then:

```
function myCtrl($stateParams) {
    console.log($stateParams.my_param);
}
```

But I need this parameter at URL then I would like to know how can I pass it with the URL string and still calling `$state.go`. Something like this:

```
$state.go('index.my_route?my_param=' + value);
> "http://localhost/#/index/my_route?my_param=123"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route should have url with query parameter.

```
.state('index.my_route', {
   url: '/index/my_route?my_param',
   ....
});
```

Now can call the state in the same way using $state.go with parameters.

Comment: perfect! And in the case if I have more than one parameter?

Comment: Got here: `url: '/index/my_route?my_param&my_param2'`. Thank you!!